# React native touchable not working with keyboard

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

I am using bare react-native CLI.

My modal has a text input field inside. In the modal, when I open the keyboard, the buttons next to the text input are not working. They close the keyboard when tapped instead of working.

I tried it using the native modal module (with KeyboardAvoidingView) and using the [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfEIN.jpg)

```html
   // with react-native-modal
  <View style={styles.PostCommentArea}>
        <View style={styles.PostBody}>
          <Image
            source={{ uri: UserDetails.profile_image }}
            style={styles.UserImg}
          />
          <InputField
            ref={InputRef}
            style={styles.InputField}
            length={0.65}
            hv={0.055}
            placeholder="Add Comment..."
            onSubmitEditing={postComment}
          />
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.PostBtn} onPress={postComment}>
            {PostingComment ? (
              <>
                <Indicator size="small" color={Colors.WHITE} />
              </>
            ) : (
              <IconOutline
                name="arrow-up"
                size={height * 0.027}
                color={Colors.WHITE}
              />
            )}
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Comment: You mentioned you are using KeyboardAvoidingView, but I don't see that on the code. Are you using it or not?

Comment: @RamaProg when using react-native-modal I am not using that. When using the native modal, I use that

Answer (score 2):

One way of fixing this is wrapping the component in a ScrollView and using the [keyboardShouldPersistTaps](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps) prop.

> 'never' tapping outside of the focused text input when the keyboard is
> up dismisses the keyboard. When this happens, children won't receive
> the tap.

> 'always', the keyboard will not dismiss automatically, and
> the scroll view will not catch taps, but children of the scroll view
> can catch taps.

> 'handled', the keyboard will not dismiss automatically
> when the tap was handled by children of the scroll view (or captured
> by an ancestor).

```
  <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>
  ...
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Tried it out with all 3 options. None of them worked

Answer (score 0):

Ensure any parent `<KeyboardAwareScrollView` or `<ScrollView`s also have this attribute, not just the immediate parent component.

Comment: This is correct, but it is not limited to ScrollView inside the modal. It also applies to a ScrollView outside the modal. The ScrollView treats the content of the modal as one of it's children.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a modal display and found that it was the ScrollView under the modal that was causing the problem.

If your modal is displayed over a ScrollView or FlatList, you need to add

keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'

That seemed to fix the problem for me.